# Get tr id values in Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I have following html table layout

```
<tbody>
  <tr id="13" role="row" class="odd">
    <td class="sorting_1">
      <input type="checkbox" class="checkall selected" id="checkall" name="checkall[]">
    </td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>4.00</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="12" class="even" role="row">
    <td class="sorting_1">
      <input id="checkall" class="checkall selected" type="checkbox" name="checkall[]">
    </td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1.00</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="11" class="odd" role="row">
    <td class="sorting_1">
      <input id="checkall" class="checkall" type="checkbox" name="checkall[]">
    </td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5.00</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Now I need to get a tr id values,only I have to get a row id values of the selected input checkboxes.
 eg: I had selected a rows id="13" and id="12" 
so I need to get a 13 and 12,not an 11.

Comment: I think you can give them upvote.

Comment: below 15 reputation not possible to upvote.

Comment: Testmail Facebook, ohh. I see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.each` to select all `checkbox` which have `selected`(or use `:checked` -> `input[type=checkbox]:checked`) class and then get the `tr id`.

By the way, your ids are invalid. According to [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-name):

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alireza_safian/50c2fkwx/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var ids = [];
  $('table input[type=checkbox].selected').each(
    function(i) {
      ids.push($(this).closest('tr').attr('id'));
    });
  $('.results').html(ids);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr id="13" role="row" class="odd">
    <td class="sorting_1">
      <input type="checkbox" class="checkall selected" id="checkall" name="checkall[]">
    </td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>4.00</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="12" class="even" role="row">
    <td class="sorting_1">
      <input id="checkall" class="checkall selected" type="checkbox" name="checkall[]">
    </td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>1.00</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>

  <tr id="11" class="odd" role="row">
    <td class="sorting_1">
      <input id="checkall" class="checkall" type="checkbox" name="checkall[]">
    </td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>5.00</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>

</table>

<div class="results"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Working fine....

Comment: @TestmailFacebook You are welcome and don't forget to change your `IDs`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it without any framework adding an inline onclick handler to each checkbox like so:

```
<input id="checkall" onclick="getRowId(this)" class="checkall selected" type="checkbox" name="checkall[]">
```

then provide the handler:

```
<script>
    function getRowId(input_elm) {
        if(input_elm.checked) {
            //console.log(input_elm.parentNode.parentNode.id);
            alert(input_elm.parentNode.parentNode.id);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with jquery like this.

```
    $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function (checkbox) {
        return $(checkbox).closest('tr').attr("id");
    });
```

It will returns all the id's of the selected rows.

Comment: I get a value as undefined.